# convert encoding of id3 tags of mp3 file

Tags: shell, character-encoding, binary, mp3, xfce4-terminal

My mp3 file has id3 tags which can be displayed in a terminal on my debian buster linux for example by using the program id3tool or id3.
If my shell (xfce4-terminal) has a set default character encoding to UTF-8, the output of id3tool looks like this:

```
Filename: test.mp3
Song Title: Qu�l Dich Fit
Artist:     Wise Guys
Album:      Frei!
Track:      16
Year:       2008
Genre:      Rock (0x11)
```

By choosing a default character encoding for the terminal to ISO-8859-1, the output of id3tool is:

```
Filename: test.mp3
Song Title: Quäl Dich Fit
Artist:     Wise Guys
Album:      Frei!
Track:      16
Year:       2008
Genre:      Rock (0x11)
```

The invalid character of the title name is gone and replaced with the correct one.
I want to be able to see the correct song title without having to switch the terminal encoding.

The mp3 file is not a text file. It is a binary with id3 tags, which apparently are encoded in ISO-8859-1.
The command

```
file -bi test.mp3
```

yields

```
audio/mpeg; charset=binary
```

Can I transform the encoding of this file to UTF-8? "iconv" works only for text files.

What else should I do to be able to work with the id3 tags of my mp3 files without invalid characters?

Comment: extract metadata to txt file with `ffmpeg`, convert it with iconv, then re-add.

Comment: ... or even read with `id3tool` and write back with `id3tool`.

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks to Ipor and Philip. I did it with id3tool. I wrote a bash script which I can call in a shell with either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 encoding and end up with a file that displays just fine in an UTF-8 encoded shell. Ipor, please copy your comment into an answer, just so I can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract metadata to txt file with `ffmpeg`, convert it with `iconv`, then re-add.